# Optical and acoustic branch

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, vibrations, phonons

Does a diatomic crystal posses both optical and acoustic branch simultaneously; Or, whether the vibration is either optical or acoustic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking, but for a crystal with $N$ atoms in the unit cell, you will get $3N$ phonon branches. The first 3 will be acoustic, and the remaining will be optical. So yes, for a diatomic crystal, we have 3 acoustic modes and 3 optical modes.

Comment: If  diatomic crystal means that the crystalline structure is described with a Bravais lattice with a basis of two atoms, there are 3 acoustic and 3 optic branches, also in according with the total $3N$ you report.